# Don't require login for anonymous users to see the pages

Tags: authentication, mediawiki

In MediaWiki, I have to set the pages so that all user are able to see the content without needing to log in. I already tried

```
 $wgGroupPermissions['*']['read'] = true;
 $wgGroupPermissions['']['createaccount'] = false; 
 $wgGroupPermissions['']['edit'] =    false; 
 $wgGroupPermissions['']['create'] = true; 
 $wgGroupPermissions['']['read'] = true;
```

but it still requires me to log in. What should I do?

Comment: Can you show us the whole config file for the permissions? Maybe there's some entry revoking it explicitly thereafter.

Comment: ``$wgGroupPermissions['*']['createaccount'] = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['edit'] = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['create'] = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['read'] = true;
`

Comment: Please [edit] them into your question, [use formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code), and then delete your comment.

Answer (score 0):

MediaWiki doesn't require login by default, so you either selected the wrong option during installation or introduced an error in the configuration.

Your error is that `''` is not a [valid group](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:User_rights): remove those lines and the configuration will work. You should also remove

```
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['read'] = true;
```

because it's the default and hence uneeded, unless you installed some extension which changes the configuration defaults, in which case you'll need to move this line after the `LocalSettings.php` line which loads the extension in question.